# Using easy_install in Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, easy-install

I'm trying to install CyLP on a windows machine in the Ubuntu for Windows app.  CyLP's documentation recommends using easy_install.  When I run the command `easy_install cylp` I get the error message

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
```

…

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

I've also tried to run `sudo easy_install cylp` and `sudo su` and then `easy_install cylp` (I'm not sure why the `sudo su` command works to access the root user but it does) and both of these return the error

```
easy_install: command not found
```

How do I go about using `easy_install` for installing CyLP?

In case you're wondering why I'm using easy_install, I'm following https://github.com/coin-or/CyLP.  Also, `pip3 install cylp` is not working; the error thrown when running that command reads

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-r0u91f_h/cylp/
```

Edit: this is the default Ubuntu app on the Microsoft store; I believe it's Ubuntu 18.04.

Update: I decided not to pursue this solution; I ran through the other installation process offered instead.  One thing that I realized after-the-fact is that I had the 'python' command associated with Python3 and this package seems to rely on Python2.

Comment: And how did you install `easy_install`?

Comment: @Biswapriyo `pip3 install setuptools`

Comment: The error isn't from WSL, it's from `cylp` side. See the `setup.py` file line #79 and #52 in that GitHub repository. The script cant detect OS type. BTW, `cylp` depends on `numpy` and `scipy` packages.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I've abandoned this; see the update.